# Browser not shows any data or Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, handlebars.js

I am using node js and angular js and handlebars as view engine. I am trying basic application / samples but not getting any data on Browser side. Data shows on browser is blank.

I did console.log on browser, I got data as [object] [object].

```
Included angular:
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
```

```
On handlebars page : [enter image description here][1]table:

<table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
    <li ng-if="records.length === 0">( No items in this list yet! )</li>

    <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
      <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{x.Country}}</td>  
    </tr>
    </table>

<script>
var app = angular.module('tennisApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = [];
    var request = $http.get('http://localhost:3030/aitaAngular');    
    request.success(function(response) {            
        $scope.data = response;  
        console.log(response);
        console.log($scope.data);
    });
    request.error(function(response){
        console.log('Error: ' + response);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: your controller name is different. use same controller name. where is your your ng-app?

Comment: you are setting data to `$scope.data` but in `ng-repeat` it is `records`.

Comment: @Dinesh I defined ng-app in body

Comment: @Pengyy oh yes. Let will try

Comment: I added ng-app in body. I forgot to add it here

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong controller name there.
You used **myCrtl** in view and **userDetails** in javascript 
There is no **ng-app** as well

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
            <body>
            <div ng-app="myApp"> 
            <table ng-controller="userDetails" border="1">
                <li ng-if="records.length === 0">( No items in this list yet! )</li>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
                  <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
                  <td>{{x.Country}}</td>  
                </tr>
                </table>                    
            </div>
            <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('userDetails', function($scope, $http) {
                $scope.data = [];
                var request = $http.get('http://localhost:3030/aitaAngular');    
                request.success(function(response) {            
                    $scope.data = response;  
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log($scope.data);
                });
                request.error(function(response){
                    console.log('Error: ' + response);
                });
            });
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```